# Logstash parse csv file

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I have a csv file that has a column that contains json object, sometimes the json input in this format that working correctly:

```
"{""field1"":""value1"",""field2"":""value2""}"
```

But sometimes it is the below format that corrupt the whole record:

```
"{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}"
```

How can I escape the single " in the second format while reading the csv file or while filtering step?